# Two addresses of a function

Tags: dll, function-pointers, memory-address

What does `GetProcAddress()` do? According to some forums, it displays a functions address in a DLL.

When I run the above function with appropriate parameters, I get the address of `printf` as some address `A`, but if I do `cout << printf`, get a different address `B`.

Why?

```
cout << GetProcAddress(
    GetModuleHandle(TEXT("MSVCRT.DLL")), 
    "printf");

cout << "****" << printf << endl;
```

Comment: The Ghost of StackOverflow says, "Uhhhhhhnnnn... Neeeeed moooore cooooode......"  @muntoo

Comment: GetProcAddress requires a module handle.  Big mystery, what exactly do you pass?  Do not LoadLibrary("msvcrt.dll"), that's nonsense.

Comment: Not enough information to know for sure, but one possibility is that the printf you got via GerProcAddress is not the one you are calling. Or you are compiling without optimizations, so you're getting the import thunk for printf. Or you are linking incrementally, so you are getting a linker thunk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Raymond
yes you are right i was getting the linker addresses in the thunk table...
thank you..